# Lifting of a Diffeomorphism to an Orientable Double Cover

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, dynamical-systems

Let $M$ be a non-orientable smooth $d$-dimensional manifold. Let $\tilde{M}$ be the oriented double cover for $M$; and let $f\in Diff^{1+\beta}(M)$. Define $\tilde{f}:\tilde{M}\rightarrow \tilde{M}$ the following way: $\tilde{f}((x,o_x)):=(f(x),o(d_xf(b)))$ where $b$ is some basis for $T_xM$ from the equivalence class $o_x$, $o(b')$ is the equivalence class of a basis $b'$.

My question is, how can one show that also $\tilde{f}\in Diff^{1+\beta}(\tilde{M})$ ?

Thanks ahead for any heplers

Comment: Short answer:  The projection map and $f$ are local diffeos, so near any point, you can invert them.  Now, locally, write $\tilde{f}$ as a composition of diffeos.

Comment: Well the important part is to show that the differential is $\beta$-H\"older, so how do I write the differential in this case? I understand I can identify it with $d_\cdot f$, but have no idea how to approach it rigorously..

Comment: I think my suggestion still works.  If you compose a $\beta$-H\"older function with a smooth $(C^\infty)$ function, the result is $\beta$-Ho"older, isn't it?  If so, that's enough because you can (locally) write $\tilde{f}$ as $\pi^{-1}\circ f\circ \pi$ and $\pi$ is $C^\infty$.

Comment: And to be clear what I mean by writing $\tilde{f}$ like that locally, pick $p\in \tilde{M}$ and let $\pi:\tilde{M}\rightarrow M$ be the covering map.  Consider $\pi(\tilde{f}(p))\in M$.  Since $\pi$ is  a covering, there is an open set $U$ around $\pi(\tilde{f}(p)$ for which $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is 2 disjoint pieces, if of which is taken by $\pi$, diffeomorphically, onto $U$.  Now, $\tilde{f}(x)$ is in one of those copies, call it $V$.  Then $\pi|_V:V\rightarrow U$ is a diffeo and on $\tilde{f}(U)$, we have $\tilde f = (\pi|_V)^{-1} \circ f \circ \pi$.

Comment: Okay I think I can take it from here, thanks!